# Get both of returned results from a method

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm working on a windows forms application, and I have a problem. In a GetDataFromFile method I'm returning 2 collections, but on buttton start how can I get them and use them as shown.

Thank you in advance and sorry if my question is stupid, but I'm a newbie and cannot figure it out

```
public Tuple<List<string>,List<string>> GetDataFromFile()
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("NotificationTasks.xml");
    var dates = doc.Descendants("Date");
    var hours = doc.Descendants("Time");
    var hoursCollection = new List<string>();
    var dateCollection = new List<string>();

    foreach (var date in dates)
    {
        dateCollection.Add(date.Value);
    }

    foreach (var hour in hours)
    {
        hoursCollection.Add(hour.Value);
    }

    return Tuple.Create(hoursCollection,dateCollection);
}


  private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

//here I must use the two collections from GetDataFromFile()

        foreach (var dates in hoursCollection)
        {
            if (dates == DateTime.Now.Date)
            {
                foreach (var hours in hoursCollection)
                {
                    StartNotificating(new TimeSpan(hours));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a tuple to receive your datatype from the method as well.

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx

```cs
public Tuple<List<string>,List<string>> GetDataFromFile()
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("NotificationTasks.xml");
    var dates = doc.Descendants("Date");
    var hours = doc.Descendants("Time");
    var hoursCollection = new List<string>();
    var dateCollection = new List<string>();

    foreach (var date in dates)
    {
        dateCollection.Add(date.Value);
    }

    foreach (var hour in hours)
    {
        hoursCollection.Add(hour.Value);
    }

    return Tuple.Create(hoursCollection,dateCollection);
}


  private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //here I must use the two collections from GetDataFromFile()
        Tuple<List<String>,List<String>> t = GetDataFromFile();
        List<String> hoursCollection = t.Item1;
        List<String> dateCollection = t.Item2;

        foreach (var dates in hoursCollection)
        {
            if (dates == DateTime.Now.Date)
            {
                foreach (var hours in hoursCollection)
                {
                    StartNotificating(new TimeSpan(hours));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could define your own class to return the data:

```
public class FileData
{
    public FileData(IEnumerable<string> hours, IEnumerable<string> dates)
    {
        Hours = hours;
        Dates = dates;
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> Hours { get; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Dates { get; }
}
```

Change the method you use to get the data:

```
public FileData GetDataFromFile()
{
    // read file etc...
    return new FileData(hoursCollection, datesCollection);
}
```

Your handler is then:

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FileData fileData = GetDataFromFile();
    var hoursCollection = fileData.Hours;
    var dateCollection = fileData.Dates;
}
```

Using a class with names for the properties will reduce the chance that you confuse `Item1` and `Item2` of the `Tuple`.